# No such element exception | Internet explorer

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

*** Updated the question with relevant html code.

I'm  facing error while trying to select any value from dropdown.
[image]

The error is

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #oHeight

I have already set all the IE settings as mentioned in [Selenium Docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration)

The code i have tried is mentioned below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Workspace\\Selenium\\Model\\servers\\IEDriverServer_32bit.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    driver.get("http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/showModalDialog2.htm");

    WebElement ddlHeight = driver.findElement(By.id("oHeight"));
    Select select = new Select(ddlHeight);
    select.selectByVisibleText("150");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Push To Create']")).click();

    driver.quit();
```

The system config is Windows 7 + IE 11

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: @DebanjanB Updated please check and let me know for any help.

Comment: Why are you using `name` instead of `id` for a select element?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov My bad i have changed it to **id** but still getting the same error.

Comment: @SandeepRaulo, after which line of code do you have this error?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov i have updated the new error message and getting the error while trying to store ref ddlHeight. I have already tried for explicit wait and javascriptexecutor but no help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code , It's working on my System : 
I'm using IE 11 + Win7 Professional:

**Code**

```
public class Sandeep {

    static WebDriver driver;
    static WebDriverWait wait;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Automation\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            InternetExplorerOptions options =  new InternetExplorerOptions();
            options.ignoreZoomSettings();
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
            driver.get("http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/showModalDialog2.htm");
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("oHeight")));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("oHeight")));
            Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("oHeight")));
            select.selectByVisibleText("150");
//          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("Push To Create")));
//          driver.findElement(By.name("Push To Create")).click();
            driver.close();

        }

    }
```

Please let me know if you have any concerns related to this.

Comment: I tried ur code as well but still getting the below error:
rg.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.id: oHeight)
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: 

I think there is some issues with the IE settings.

Comment: Could be something wrong with IE. You can try this code on different/virtual machines , cause it's working extremely good in my system.

Comment: Have you made any changes in ur IE settings? If yes pls share it with me.

Comment: When I opened IE yesterday, there was some pop up for making IE default browsers  , I chose "don't ask me again " option , and it worked.

Comment: oh. Then hard luck for me. I have made all the changes as per given in Selenium docs but no solutions.

Comment: Try to take IE update, you never know it might work !

Comment: No issues  then !